# MonoTouch How To: Get Title/Subtitle from Selected Annotation, Set Custom Property, Use Event Object

Tags: ios, properties, event-handling, annotations, xamarin.ios

1st Question: How do I get the title and subtitle of a selected annotation?

2nd Question: How do I set a custom property such as 'placemark id' so that I can use it to fetch details from a datastore?

3rd Question: How do I use the event object that is thrown in say: mapview.DidDeselectAnnotationView += (o, e) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Given an annotation "a", you do:

   ```
   a.Title = "My Title";
   a.Subtitle = "My Subtitle";
   ```
2. I do not quite understand the question, can you post a code snippet?
3. the type of the "o, e" in your sample is (object sender, MKAnnotationViewEventArgs eventArgs).

The "sender"  corresponds to the MKMapView that sent the event, but you probably have that already.

The "evt" contains a property "view" which is of type MKAnnotationView which corresponds to the MKAnnotationView that is being displayed.